# gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart.so.6.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

Please help! Currently I am working with oculus rift, installed ros and I tried to install gazebo cmake and make passed, but when I tried to run gazebo the output is following: 
gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart.so.6.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Also tried to install libdart6 packages, but nothing seems to work. I am desperate here. Pls help

Comment: hey, did you try ``ldd gzserver`` and check the output for missing libs there? also you might add your operating system, because the library packages usually have distinct names on each distribution

Comment: ldd: ./gzserver: No such file or directory
i am using linux mint

Comment: that error is telling you that the argument to ldd, which is "./gzserver", is not there, where you look for it. better specify a full absolute path to the gzserver binary you want to run. like ``ldd /home/zujankaaa/gzserver/gzserver``. the command you issued only works, if you sit inside the directory where the gzserver binary is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **missing a dependencies for your software**. there is a shared object (a .so file) that is still missing in the path. A path usually is a list of directories, where software looks for its dependencies.

if you are in a directory called `/home/random/another/dir/`
and this directory contains a executable file, you can execite it via

```
./executable
```

the `./` indicates that the shell searches `executable` in the current working directory. I most shells the ./ only is necessary if you want to run an executable.

If any software complains about missing dependecies you can use the `ldd` to check for those.
**first ensure you are in the right directory**, then run `ldd executable_file`

Ill give you an example here:

```
g@toolbox:~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86$ ls
CHANGELOG     imageformats    libQt5Core.so.5     libQt5Sql.so.5      libquazip.so  platforms        qt.conf        sqldrivers    ts3client_linux_x86
error_report  libc++abi.so.1  libQt5Gui.so.5      libQt5Widgets.so.5  news          plugins          sound          styles        ts3client_runscript.sh
gfx           libc++.so.1     libQt5Network.so.5  libQt5XcbQpa.so.5   package_inst  plugin_sdk.html  soundbackends  translations  update
g@toolbox:~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86$ ldd ts3client_linux_x86 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf770a000)
    libquazip.so => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xf76ea000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xf76e0000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf76c3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xf767d000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xf7145000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xf6bc5000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0xf6a36000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xf6337000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0xf62ed000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xf62d5000)
    **libc++.so.1 => not found
    libc++abi.so.1 => not found**
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf62b7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xf629b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf60ee000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56607000)
    libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0xf5ecb000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0xf5d47000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf5c1f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf5b2d000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf5b00000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xf5aa3000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf598b000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf592d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf57db000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0xf416e000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf40fa000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf4048000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf4020000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.340.102 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.102 (0xf401b000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.340.102 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.102 (0xf1a87000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf1a72000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf1a69000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf1a43000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf1a3f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf1a39000)
g@toolbox:~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86$
```

as you can see my **ts3client_linux_x86** executable would be missing `libc++.so.1,    libc++abi.so.1`

you use these names as hints on what package to install.

Linux Mint uses **apt-get** like Debian/Ubuntu to install software. The documentation for those two is a bit better than on Mint (at least in quantity and accessibility terms). So **you might benefit searching for debian/ubuntu documentation**, too, if on Linux Mint.

back to your problem:
ldd would not tell you more than you already knew, i.e. that you are missing this shared object `libdart.so.6.1`

I can not find it in standart debian jessie and a bit of searching seems to indicate that you need to configure a ppa first to get it. thats a bit messy.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source

this link above states, that:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dartsim
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdart-core5-dev
```

can be used to add said ppa, and might install "a libdart library". It might be 
`libdart.so.5.1` but not `libdart.so.6.1`

I however cannot be arsed to check myself ;)
What you could do now, is add the ppa, update apt and try to `apt-get install libdart-core6-dev`

And perhaps be lucky. (just dont follow the instructions on the page, they might be unrelated to your personal goal)

Good Look with finding a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for your help!
In the end I went to dart's page, downloaded dart.6.1.2, extracted it, build it and then it worked. Fell kinda like a idiot haha. Your sugestions helped me a lot! T